# ES 2.0 Multi-Pass & Render to Texture Implementation

Tags: iphone, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I need help setting up multi-pass rendering with OpenGL ES 2.0 on the iPhone.  I haven't been able to find an example which implements both rendering to a texture and multi-pass shading.

I'm looking for some instructions and sample code which implement:

- First stage: Render to a texture
- Second stage: Input that texture and render to screen

I have referenced Apple's [OpenGL ES Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/), OpenGL Shading Language (Orange Book), and O'Reilly's iPhone 3D Programming Book.

The Orange Book discusses deferred shading and provides two shader programs for first-pass and second-pass rendering, but doesn't provide example code to setup that application or show how to communicate data between both shaders.

**Questions:**

- How to render to texture?

  - Using glDrawElements
  - How to input that texture to the next pass?
- How to implement two shading programs?
- How to alternate first- and second-pass shading programs?

  - Need to attach, detach, and call 'use' for each pass?
- How to implement multi-pass shading?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a short example of doing just this (multiple render-to-texture passes on the iPhone using OpenGL ES 2.0) a few weeks ago: http://www.mat.ucsb.edu/a.forbes/blog/?p=245

**

Edit, this post is a bit old, and it has moved here: 
http://blog.angusforbes.com/openglglsl-render-to-texture/

**

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work. It just open your Blog at the homepage. Could you kindly write the right link?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, first of all: I'm no expert on OpenGL ES 2.0. I was kind of in the same situation where I wanted to do a multipass render setup, in one of my first OpenGL ES applications.

I also used the Orange Book. Check chapter *12. Framebuffer Objects > Examples*. The first example demonstrates how to use a framebuffer to render to a texture, and then draws that texture to screen.

Basically using that example I created an application that renders some geometry to a texture using an effect shader, then renders that texture to screen, layered with some other content all using a different shader.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it works for my purposes. My setup:

- I create two framebuffers, the default and an offscreen one. Same for the renderbuffers
- I create a texture which the app will render to
- I bind the offscreen framebuffer, and attach the texture to it using glFramebufferTexture2D

My rendering:

- bind the offscreen framebuffer.
- use my first shader program
- draw my geometry
- bind the default framebuffer
- use my second shader program
- draw a fullscreen quad with the texture attached to it.